# How to call a function on a website from a background-script in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to execute a function in a chrome-tab from a background script.

I want to show the current youtube-video-url in my popup.html file, but for some reason my javascript-code does not work the expected way.

`popup.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
  }
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = message;
});
```

`payload.js`

```
setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);

function oneSecondFunction() {
    if (!document.hidden) {
        video = document.getElementById("movie_player");
        if(video) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage("Video playing: " + video.getVideoUrl());
        } else {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage("No video playing!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you paste `document.getElementById("movie_player").getVideoUrl()` in the chrome-console, you get the video-url (if you are on youtube). The code shown above should give me the video-url too but insteads leads to this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: video.getVideoUrl is not a function`

I don't need another way of getting the current url of the tab as I also wanna execute some other functions on this object (which always tell me that they are no functions, though they can be executed in a chrome console).

Comment: Since content script code runs in an isolated world you need to delve a bit deeper and [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879). Also, 1) no need for chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() and 2) note that the popup doesn't run when it's hidden so don't forget to stop your timer when no response is received from the popup (use a callback for sendMessage and send a response as shown in the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) documentation).

Comment: okay, thanks, this really helped my, but I also want to access chrome.storage.sync from this content script, is this possible?

Comment: A content script can do it. A page script created by the content script cannot. You'll have to use DOM messaging between the two scripts via CustomEvent as the other answers in that linked topic show.